# Private Notes In Woocommerce Order List

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We add our own production numbers in private notes and it would be really handy if we could show these private notes on the order list under a new column, searched all over the internet but none of the codes have worked.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code snippet in function.php file:

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcol_custom_row', 'wpo_wcol_order_notes', 10, 1 );
function wpo_wcol_order_notes ( $order_id ) {
    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'type'     => 'customer', // use 'internal' for admin and system notes, empty for all
    ) );

    if ( $notes ) {
        foreach( $notes as $key => $note ) {
            // system notes can be identified by $note->added_by == 'system'
            printf( '<div class="note_content">%s</div>', wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( make_clickable( $note->content ) ) ) ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't thing this is a right answer. The hook you used `wpo_wcol_order_notes` is specific for the plugin `WooCommerce Print Order List` and it will not work if don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have code to display private notes in Woocommerce order list:

```php
  // WooCommerce - Add order notes column to orders list
  // Code goes in functions.php for your child theme
  // not tested in a PHP snippet plugin
  
  // Add column "Order Notes" on the orders page
  add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_order_notes_column' );
  function add_order_notes_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = ( is_array( $columns ) ) ? $columns : array();
    $new_columns['order_notes'] = 'Order Notes';
    return $new_columns;
  }
  
  add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'add_order_notes_column_style' );
  function add_order_notes_column_style() {
    $css = '.post-type-shop_order table.widefat.fixed { table-layout: auto; width: 100%; }';
    $css .= 'table.wp-list-table .column-order_notes { min-width: 280px; text-align: left; }';
    $css .= '.column-order_notes ul { margin: 0 0 0 18px; list-style-type: disc; }';
    $css .= '.order_customer_note { color: #ee0000; }'; // red
    $css .= '.order_private_note { color: #0000ee; }'; // blue
    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles', $css );
  }
  
  // Add order notes to the "Order Notes" column
  add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_order_notes_content' );
  function add_order_notes_content( $column ) {
    if( $column != 'order_notes' ) return;      
    global $post, $the_order;
    if( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() != $post->ID ) {
      $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    }    
    $args = array();
    $args['order_id'] = $the_order->get_id();
    $args['order_by'] = 'date_created';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( $args );
    if( $notes ) {
      print '<ul>';
      foreach( $notes as $note ) {
        if( $note->customer_note ) {
          print '<li class="order_customer_note">';
        } else {
          print '<li class="order_private_note">';
        }
        $date = date( 'd/m/y H:i', strtotime( $note->date_created ) );
        print $date.' by '.$note->added_by.'<br>'.$note->content.'</li>';
      }
      print '</ul>';
    }
  } // end function
```

Just copy and paste the code into your `functions.php` file.

Credits: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-private-note-column-on-woocommerce-order-page/